# Php upload file then crop

Tags: php, gd

i'm on a cordova project. i use Jquery and the Jcrop plugin and Php gd in my server side.
When i upload user's avatar i try to crop the picture.
The upload is going well, but nothing happens for the crop.

the php code:

```
    if(move_uploaded_file($file,$dirname."/avatar.jpeg")){
        $targ_w = $targ_h = 150;
        $src =   $dirname.'/avatar.jpeg';
        $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
        $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );
        imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['avatar_x'],$_POST['avatar_y'], $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['avatar_w'],$_POST['avatar_h']);
    }else{...}
```

i have no error message

Comment: You have no error message? Have you enabled error checking?

Comment: You should save the image after your `imagecopyresampled`.

Comment: error checking is enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing happens because you're not doing anything with the result. See [the documentation for `imagecopyresampled`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php):

> `imagecopyresampled()` will take a rectangular area from `src_image` [...] and place it in a rectangular area of `dst_image`.

After running this function, the result will be in `$dst_r`, which is still an in-memory image resource. You now have to save it to a file. This can be done with the [`imagejpeg` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php), for example:

```
imagejpeg($dst_r, "$dirname/avatar_cropped.jpeg");
```